# Processing while read line remotely via ssh doesn't fill read variable

Tags: bash, ssh, while-loop

I'm trying to remotely process a while read line loop via ssh with the following:

```
ssh /root/.ssh/id_rsa "while read var; do echo \"- $var -\"; done < /tmp/file; cat /tmp/file"
```

/tmp/file exists remotely. Output of the command should be:

```
- /tmp -
- /var -
/tmp
/var
```

But output actually is:

```
- -
- -
/tmp
/var
```

Why doesn't $var get filled here when remotely executed ?
If I happen to connect a console via ssh to the machine and execute the same command, it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use single quotes or escape the `$` in `$var`. Right now `$var` is getting substituted before ssh runs.

```
ssh /root/.ssh/id_rsa 'while read var; do echo "- $var -"; done < /tmp/file; cat /tmp/file'
```

Comment: Added double quotes and the - sign just for sake of tests. Escaping double quotes or replacing by echo $var without doublequotes doesn't change expected result.

Comment: Actually the problem is using double quotes. See my updated answer.

Comment: Indeed... I should have thought about variable substitution instead of playing around for an hour trying to see what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$var` is getting expanded before the `ssh` because it's inside double quotes.  If you make the command you're passing to `ssh` be in single quotes it won't get expanded, or if you escape the `$` you should be set:

```
ssh /root/.ssh/id_rsa 'while read var; do echo "- $var -"; done < /tmp/file; cat /tmp/file'
```

or

```
ssh /root/.ssh/id_rsa "while read var; do echo \"- \$var -\"; done < /tmp/file; cat /tmp/file"
```